# Django - dynamic model for TemplateView class-based

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I want to switch between two models depending on which route I am in.

I am overwriting `get_queryset()` function to return the correct model:

```
class DynamicModelView(TemplateView, PageDescriptionListingMixin):

    model = None
    template_name = 'dynamic_model.html'
    context_object_name = "accounts"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DynamicModelView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        self.add_page_text_to_context(context)
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        if '/dynamic_user/' in self.request.path:
            model = UserAccount
        else:
            model = AdminAccount
        return model.objects.first()
```

As you can see in `get_context_data` I am injecting an object in context for **AdminAccount** but inside template I can't see it! in fact if I changed `model` from `None` to **AdminAccount** then it appears which I want that to happen dynamically.

Is there any way to switch models dynamically in Django?

Answer (score 0):

override dispatch method.

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.model:
        self.model = <MODEL>
    return super(DynamicModelView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```